# How to properly utilize PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

*Quick Edit*: Although it says MAMP, I just store my web projects there and I do not utilize the mysql server it provides (though when I tried it threw the same error), I use the mysql that came with MySQL workbench*

In the php code I am working on I connect to my database as follows:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass);
```

Now, I tested the user and password for the database both via my terminal (Which connects successfully), along with the interface my IDE (phpStorm) provides which also successfully connects.

My issue is as follows: How to get past the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GIS/4Musketeers/PHP/common.php:20

Now I know it mentions line 20 which refers to the start of my foreach block:

```
function printDirectors($sqlQuery) {
    $index = 0; //Counting index for our table
    global $dbh; //this is how we refer to our global $dbh up top.

    foreach ($dbh->query($sqlQuery) as $result) {
        echo "<tr><td class=\"index\">";
        echo $index + 1 ."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"FirstName\">";
        echo $result['first_name'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"LastName\">";
        echo $result['last_name'];
        echo "</td></tr>";
        $index++;
    }
}
```

I am quite confident that the query is correct as it does provide me the result I am interested in. Query being:

```
SELECT DISTINCT directors.first_name, directors.last_name
FROM directors, actors
WHERE directors.first_name = actors.first_name AND directors.last_name = actors.last_name
ORDER BY directors.first_name, directors.last_name;
```

And the result being:

```
first_name     last_name
Andrew         Adamson
Guy            Ritchie
James (I)      Cameron
Jay            Levey
Mel (I)        Gibson
```

This is the first time I actually have to use PDO or SQL with PHP, so any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question has already been asked dozens of times here on SO. The solution always is to make sure that your pdo connection is created and visible to this method call.

Comment: i would suggest you to learn rebdeanphp which is build on PDO. But it is really simple .

Comment: Well, see, the amusing thing is that I tried running it again and it went through just fine. And I know, I did look into that question, except my issue was query and not prepare.

Comment: The root cause is the same.

Comment: I assume in that one the user simply started using the supposed PDO without creating it, I did call new PDO() at the top. As far as I am aware, that was the solution provided.

Comment: In your wuestion it is unclear as to where exactly the pdo connection is created and where it used. And I repeat: the root cause is the same, you do not have a properly initialised pdo connection created when you try to invoke its methods. It is up to you to find the issue in your code.

Comment: Well the issue seems to have self resolved. The PDO is called before the function, it is a global variable. Hence the global keyword inside the function as otherwise I cannot access the dbh variable within my function. The issue probably is the same, but it magically resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output states, the reason you are getting this is because you never instantiated `$dbh`. PHP tries to call the `query` method on it, but it is null.

Comment: I was under the impression that `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass);` fulfilled that, and that sine $dbh sits above my function, that is a global variable, I simply reference it as global $dbh, then use $dbh as any other variable within my function. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Interestingly, you are correct, when I moved my dbh into the function it worked. But this seems to go against the purpose behind global though, right?

Comment: That is odd. According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), that should work. I'm not saying this is the correct way to do it, but when I was writing PHP code I would just create a method that returned an instance of a PDO.